# Color not loaded from assets with SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, uicolor, xcasset

I have this simple view :

```
struct SplashscreenView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color("primary").edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            Text("Hello, World!")
        }

    }
}
```

The color `primary` is defined in `Assets.xcassets` :

[image]

But in my view, color is not displayed :

[image]

If i force with system's color, like Color.red, the color is correctly displayed.

Comment: i just tried this - it works. are you assets part of your project?

Comment: I have create a framework to host my view and asset

Comment: then use Color( with the Bundle init....

Comment: It seems to be a system issue. I tested on multiple machines. Most of them can load the Colour using Color("name") from asset catalog. But one of the Mac mini 11.5 beta cannot load the colours.